# video filter adjust not working on rasperry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, vlc

I am trying to view a video via CVLC on a raspberry pi zero by using this command...

```
cvlc --no-osd --video-filter=adjust --brightness=2.0 /mnt/flash-drive/16-16-05.mp4
```

The video plays without any issues when i leave out the "--video-filter=adjust --brightness=2.0" section.
But when i add that section VLC does not show the video.

I looked around on the web on how to adjust image settings like brightness and contrast from command line and that seems to be the way , i just don't understand why it doesn't work on the raspberry pi zero.

Any idea why that doesn't work ?

EDIT :

This function is not supported on the raspberry pi because of its hardware acceleration.

Comment: What does your edit mean? Is that the answer? If so, please add it as an actual answer, along with the source of where you found it and accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This function is not supported on the raspberry pi because of its hardware acceleration.

[VLC BUG REPORT WEBSITE](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc/-/issues/25973)